# How to make a top 10 node list in drupal

Tags: drupal, cck

I am trying to make a **View with "Top 10" nodes** where the position is granted by an administrator through a CCK text field with 10 options (1 to 10 points).

I want that **once an option is chosen, that option is not available in the select lists of other nodes.** In other words, when an option is selected (for example "9th position") in a node, this option is removed from the list (other nodes will have all but "9th").

When a node has its position removed, that option appears as well. This can also be achieved through a **special validation snippet: the options are all available but when one that is already chosen is selected it displays an error or warning.**

UPDATE: it just occurred to me that another (much better) option is to **have an admin page with a list of ten top nodes** that can be rearranged, removed or added.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [NodeQueue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module. This provides the ability to create fixed lists of nodes.